# Unpredictable directionality of the edge label texts with tikz automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I'm have a wired situation when I'm fine-tuning the edge position between 2 states with *\usetikzlibrary{automata}*.

An example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
[
  initial/.style={line width=1pt},
  accepting by double/.append style={line width=1pt},
  semithick,
]
    \draw node (a) [state] at (3, 1) {\footnotesize $a$};
    \draw node (b) [state] at (3, -1) {\footnotesize $b$};
    \path[->] (a) edge [in=120,out=240,looseness=0] node[sloped] {>} (b);
    \path[->] (a) edge [in=100,out=260,looseness=0] node[sloped] {>} (b);
    \path[->] (a) edge [in=80,out=280,looseness=0] node[sloped] {>} (b);
    \path[->] (a) edge [in=60,out=300,looseness=0] node[sloped] {>} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the output using LaTeXiT, where the texts for 2nd and 4th edge go backwards.

[image: This is the output using LaTeXiT]

What more interesting is pdflatex generates a different but still unpredictable texts:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You have a really interesting way of drawing straight lines. I tought `to[bend left=0]` was original but you clearly beat me. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @marmot! I leant it from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69216/increase-the-bending-distance-of-a-to-path-in-tikz)!

Comment: Thanks. Tom Bombadil didn't go to zero. It is OK to go to zero, I think, but then there can be side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get predictable "texts", refrain from drawing the straight lines in that complicated fashion. If you want to start at a certain angle from a node, you do not have to use `out=...,in=...`, it suffices to specify the angles in the starting node and target.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  initial/.style={line width=1pt},
  accepting by double/.append style={line width=1pt},
  semithick,
]
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\tiny}}

    \draw node (a) [state] at (3, 1) {\footnotesize $a$};
    \draw node (b) [state] at (3, -1) {\footnotesize $b$};
    \path[->] (a.240) edge[">",sloped,pos=0.3]  (b.120);
    \path[->] (a.260) edge[">",sloped,pos=0.3]  (b.100);
    \path[->] (a.280) edge[">",sloped,pos=0.3]  (b.80);
    \path[->] (a.300) edge[">",sloped,pos=0.3]  (b.60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this gives reliable predictable results.

Another way to get the result is to do

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  initial/.style={line width=1pt},
  accepting by double/.append style={line width=1pt},
  semithick,
]
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\tiny}}

    \draw node (a) [state] at (3, 1) {\footnotesize $a$};
    \draw node (b) [state] at (3, -1) {\footnotesize $b$};
     \draw[->] (a.240) --  (b.120) node[midway,sloped] {>};
     \draw[->] (a.260) -- (b.100) node[midway,sloped] {>};
     \draw[->] (a.280) -- (b.80) node[midway,sloped] {>};
     \draw[->] (a.300) -- (b.60) node[midway,sloped] {>};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which does not rely on `quotes`. Why is that all happening? Ti*k*Z was written by a European, so text flows from left to right. So if the path ends at a larger `x` coordinate then it started, the text direction is opposite from what it is when the the path ends at a smaller `x` coordinate then it started. So far, so predictable. What you have found is curious effect when the lines are vertical, in which Ti*k*Z must make an ad hoc choice, and, due to the construction of the lines as curves of looseness=0, rounding errors kicked in. These rounding errors are, however, not limited to this situation, it seems.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\tiny}}
\foreach \X in {0,5,...,355}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{90+2*sin(\X)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  initial/.style={line width=1pt},
  accepting by double/.append style={line width=1pt},
  semithick,
]
\path[use as bounding box] (2,-2) rectangle (4,2);
    \draw node (a) [state] at (3, 1) {\footnotesize $a$};
    \node[anchor=west] at (3.2,0) {\Y};
    \node[anchor=east] at (2.8,0) {\X};
    \draw node (b) [state] at (3, -1) {\footnotesize $\X$};
    \draw[->] (a.270) -- (b.\Y) node[midway,sloped] {>};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that the `looseness=0` is really where the randomness comes from! I got predictable result by setting  `looseness=.00001` and text goes backwards with `looseness=-.00001`. I worked out a minimal correction in my question by `\path[->] (a.260) edge node[sloped] {>} (b.100);`. Thanks for letting me know the angle can be referred in this way!

Comment: @Laplace_wdd Thanks! Yes, that's what I thought.

Comment: Hi @marmot, sorry for bothering again. But could you try to add `\path[->] (a.250) edge[">",sloped,pos=0.3]  (b.130);` into your solution and see what's going on? I was modifying my code based on yours but a typo triggered this.

Comment: @Laplace_wdd This works but clearly `\path[->] (a.250) edge[">",sloped,pos=0.3] (b.110);` looks better. BTW, what are you trying to do with the `>` signs? If you want to have arrow heads in the middle of the path, there are much better options...

Comment: ">" is just showing the correct text directionality for this question. Regarding that extra line of code, I got unpredicted text position as well. Should I update the question to include that? I don't know how to reply with pic (new here)

Comment: @Laplace_wdd It's quite interesting. If you want to see something that is arguably even more crazy, try `\draw[->] (a.250) to (b.130) node[midway,sloped] {>};`. If you want to solve the issue, do `\draw[->] (a.250) -- (b.130) node[midway,sloped] {>};` instead. If you want, I can add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the second gives me an unexpected output too (> goes backwards)

Comment: @Laplace_wdd I am not sure if I would call them "unpredictable". Ti*k*Z takes the direction of the text to be from left to right. So if the path ends at a larger x coordinate then it started, the text direction is opposite from what it is when the  the path ends at a smaller x coordinate then it started. So far, so predictable. What you have found is curious effect when the lines are vertical, in which Ti*k*Z must make an ad hoc choice, and, due to the construction of the lines as curves of `looseness=0`, rounding errors kicked in.

Comment: This is a good summary of the issue. Would you like to put this into the answer?

Comment: @Laplace_wdd Done. There are even more rounding issues, it seems.

Comment: @Laplace_wdd ... and also more disturbing that I would have thought ... I *really* thought that it is just the unconventional way of drawing straight lines, but no, you seem to have discovered something much more dramatic... ;-)